# How to run a multiple module project using Maven on NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have 2 OSGi Bundles as Services in a NetBeans IDE Maven Multi-Module project. The only way I so far know to go about Building and Deploying the OSGi Bundles is as explained [**HERE** : Building and Deploying the OSGi Bundles](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-osgiservice-cdi.html#div.indent:nth-child%2828%29%20%3E%20h3:nth-child%2810%29)

To run any of the bundles, I have to go to the GlassFish OSGi Administration Console Bundles and Click on the **START / STOP** tab to run a bundle to print the necessary items to the console (As explained in the "[**Building and Deploying the OSGi Bundles**](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-osgiservice-cdi.html#Exercise_4)" part of the tutorial). All this just to run this onto the console:

```
System.out.println("HelloActivator::start");
context.registerService(Hello.class.getName(), new HelloImpl(), null);
System.out.println("HelloActivator::registration of Hello service successful");
```

The problem is that this seems a very long process. Is there another way to have a similar functionality, like what I can achieve with a non Multi-Module project, whereby I can just click on the NetBeans **Run** tab and have the project print my `System.out.println("Hello World")` to console.

I would like to run all the modules in a similar way by clicking on the run button.